# How to Extend the Request/Connection Timeout on Apache-FastCGI-PHP application using .htaccess

Tags: php, timeout, connection

I am trying to extend the Connection/Request Timeout at our allotted server space.

The Reason i am trying to do this is, for some operations in my application takes more than 120 seconds, then the server is not waiting for the operation to complete. It returns **500 Internal Server Error**, exactly after 120 seconds.

To test it i placed the below script on server:

```
<?php
sleep(119);
echo "TEST";
?>
```

It will return TEST, to the browser after 119 seconds.

But when i place below script:

```
<?php
sleep(121);
echo "TEST";
?>
```

It will return **500 Internal Server Error** after 120 seconds

we have set the **Max_execution_time=360** in php.ini, but the problem still exists.

We have Apache installed with FastCGI.

I am trying to extend it to 360 seconds, using .htaccess, because that is the only way i can in Shared Hosting.

Any solutions or Suggestions ?, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6):

Fastcgi is a different beast; using set_time_limit will not solve the problem.  I'm not sure what you can do with .htaccess, but the normal setting you're looking for is called IPCCommTimeout; you can try to change that in the .htaccess, I'm not sure if it's allowed or not.

See the directives on the [apache fcgid page](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html); if you're using an old version, you might need to try setting FcgidIOTimeout instead.

I would suggest that 120 seconds is far too long for a user to wait for a request over a web server; if things take this long to run, try running your script from the command line with PHP CLI instead.

Comment: I added below lines to .htaccess, it has become worst- returns 500 internal server error immediately. May be its not the place to add.<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
IPCCommTimeout 150
</IfModule>

Comment: Mahesh, try FcgidIOTimeout instead (see my comment), it's for older versions, otherwise you probably can't mess with this setting in .htaccess.

Comment: Yobo, foreach directive there is a Context mentioned, only the directives having Context:directory, .htaccess, can be included in .htaccess Right?

Comment: Yes, you're right; and the context for FcgidIOTimeout is server config, virtual host, so I think you're out of luck, sorry.

Comment: some times my application takes more than 40 seconds to respond, it may increase. So i am trying to remove/extend the timeout, so that it doesn't send 500 server error. In my localhost, which has php installed as apache module, there is no timeout, it waits for 10 minutes also :)

Comment: You made my day, the IPCCommTimeout was the parameter I was looking for! I use FastCGI with my local development webserver, and my PHPMyAdmin always resulted in a 500 error when trying to import large datases. Setting that parameter on a higher value and restarting Apache solved this problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -5):

Try this, hope it will work:

```
set_time_limit(int seconds)
```

Comment: set_time_limit doesnt solve the problem when the php module is used in fcgi